# React Router not loading component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am relatively new to React and can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working!

This code is not loading the App component inside router, but it does when returned independently. Example below

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "../components/App";
import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Route path="/">
        <App />
      </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
  );
});
```

Nothing loads on the screen with this. However when I remove the router I see the App component load:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "../components/App";
import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    // <Router>
    //   <Route path="/">
    //     <App />
    //   </Route>
    // </Router>,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
  );
});
```

Finally, this is my App component (dont think you need this though)

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return <div>app has loaded</div>;
};
export default App;
```

This is built on a Ruby on Rails app, if that matters

Comment: what a version of your ```react-router-dom``` ?

Answer (score 1):

if you'are using `react-router-dom` v5:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "../components/App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Switch>
         <Route path="/">
            <App />
         </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
  );
});
```

if you're using `react-router-dom` v6

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "../components/App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Routes>
         <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```js
import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

try

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: still nothing
```import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "../components/App";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/">
        <App />
      </Route>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What versions of react and react-router-dom are you using?  This works for me in a fresh `npx create-react-app`:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"; // BrowserRouter as Router
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>,

    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "../components/App";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <App />
          </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed all the steps, then the answer may just be that you installed the NPM package in the wrong place.

Make sure it is in your project folders JSON file.
Considering you're new to React it is pretty easy to install packages in the wrong place.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).